# Backbone.localStorage + RequireJS: Not working?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, requirejs

Collection definition:

```
define(function(require) {
    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        m = require('../models/m');
        require('backbone.localstorage');

    var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: m,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('queue')
    });

    return new c();
});
```

In View:

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        c = require('../collections/c');

    var v = Backbone.View.extend({
        ...
        events: {
            'click div': 'updateQueue'
        },
        updateQueue: function($_event) {
            c.add(this.model);
        }
    });

    return v;
});
```

The `c.add(this.model);` line doesn't work at all, and the Collection never gets saved into localStorage, losing all Models on each page reload. Any idea where I did wrong? I'm using the newest Backbone.localStorage version for Github.

**EDIT:**

Changed to `c.create()` instead and it's still not saving anything to localStorage. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `c.add(this.model);` event called, or is it requirejs problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug:

```
updateQueue: function($_event) {
    c.create(this.model);          // wrong
    c.create(this.model.toJSON()); // correct!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the create() function `c.create(this.model);`, this automatically saves your model.
Or you can save the model before you add it to collection

Comment: Changed to c.create() instead and it's still not saving anything to localStorage. Any ideas?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devendra/KY2db/11/) well its working in this fiddle

Comment: Nice fiddle deven! The real issue though is `this.model` isn't what should be added/created, but `this.model.toJSON()` instead ;)

Comment: when you pass this.model.toJSON() to create() function. Internally it checks whether passed in argument is a backone model, if not creates one with whatever attributes you passed and then adds it to collection 
So its like repeating the process of creating model that you already done . However if your error is solved then its ok :)

Answer (score 0):

If you added the model to collection, it doen't mean it's got saved. You have to call save method, by yourself.

Good recommendation to use `create` instead.